# Is there any way to find out changed file after some date in whole project code?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

see i am working in one BIG project source code Now i want to know which files are modified after some date.

Is there any command or any way to get that..

i have tried

```
# ls -R -l
```

but here it shows all file with last modified data but i want to filter this output by some data ...

so is there any way to do this in linux? is there any tool available for this?

Comment: What is the scm tool? Almost all version control tools comes with good query mechanisms

Comment: find has different options to provide list based on access dates

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
#set timestamp for file    
touch --date "2011-12-31" /tmp/foo
# Find files newer than 2011/Dec/31, in /some/files
find /some/files -newer /tmp/foo
```

Comment: After a specific time:
touch -d  '2011-12-31 10:22' /tmp/foo

Comment: what is /tmp/foo? 
How can I do this:
find files in this-directory that mmtime > this-date and save it as variable lst?
Thank you

Comment: `/tmp/foo` is an arbitrary file that is just used to compare the date too. It is placed in `/tmp` as it is a temporary file.

Answer (score 36):

Use *find* command with **mtime** arguments:  [Some examples are here](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html) or [here](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm)

For example, list files changed in last 7 days...

```
find / -type f -mtime -7
```

For *fine* grained search you may try -mmin argument. See an example discussed in another SE site: [Find All files older than x minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/383123/find-all-files-older-than-one-minute)

Comment: The problem with mtime is that it's too coarse. If you have files modified 6 hours ago and 8 hours ago, you can't distinguish them with find. You'll need to use [peko's workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8986162/111424).

Comment: This command gives the files modified 7*24 hours ago not those which got changed in last 7 days.

Comment: Is there away to to skip certain subfolders with a speficic keywords(s) stay "cache" and "log"?  for example.  ```find / -type f -mtime -7  -skip "cache,log" ?``` thanks.

Comment: The example with `-mtime -7` does find all objects changed in the last 7 days. Not just 7*24 ago.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `find` with `-newerXY` option.

- m – modification time of the file reference
- t – reference is interpreted directly as a time

All files modified after 2022-12-01 (inclusive):

```
find . -type f -newermt 2022-12-01
```